# Twilio: client to client call across subaccounts

Tags: twilio

I am working on Twilio APIs for client to client call. Everything is working fine with main account.

Now I have created a sub account and I wanted o see how the call connections are made across the sub accounts.

Using the sub account's account sid and auth token I am able to make outbound calls to phone numbers and is connecting fine.

Now when I tried to connect another client who has registered with the master accounts sid and auth token, I get the status as an answered even-though no call came at the other client end. And it is not at all connecting

And I noticed that even conference names are not visible across sub accounts. That is I tried to call to same conference room from different sub accounts of the same main account, but the users did not connect each other.

What could be the reason. How can I connect clients across sub accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to understand from Twilio that calls can not be connected across sub accounts.

Comment: Hello sir .. are you sure about this ? as i am also trying to perform the same thing.

Comment: Yup. I confirmed it with Twilio team while in last year march.

Comment: so what is the alternative to this ? what solution you got for the same .. As i want to call between two different sub accounts who have different account sid and auth token. how can i can between these sub accounts ?

Comment: Actually I thought of using different sub accounts for different users initially. But later I I understood that my requirement does not need separate sub accounts. All calls from different clients are managed within our single account and through the database entries of clients.